# How to transfer data from one schema to another schema of different machine in Postgres db using Dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have a Postgres database schema in machine A, I want to copy the whole database schema into machine B using [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
To use DBeaver to export a schema you can right click on the schema and then tools > backup. There select the schema you want to export. Details can be found [here](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Backup-Restore/)

You should take the backup using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html). To take a dump from a remote server you should run the following

```bash
pg_dump -h host_address -U username -s schema_name -Fc database_name > dump_file_path.sql
```

This will create a SQL dump of the selected schema. Then you can use PSQL or DBeaver to import and create the schema in your server B or database B.

To do it with psql you should run the following -

```bash
psql "sslmode=disable dbname=_db_name_ user=_user_ hostaddr=_host_" < exported_sql_file_path
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Hi @Shayne I've updated the answer to include dbeaver built in option. But can you please tell me why my answer doesn't cover the question? To use Dbeaver's export/import you have to have psql client anyways.

Comment: Because it asks:
How to transfer data from one schema to another schema of different machine in Postgres db using Dbeaver

And you didnt answer that. You answered something else.

And neither does your new answer. (DBeaver backup backs up to a local file.)